# Changing a ListView item color without using onClickListener()

Tags: android, listview

I have this activity:
[Activity_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiNy1.png)

When I click in one day the list view below calendar show the subjects of the day. But some days have absence, so when i click in the day with absence I wanna show in red the list view item. How can I do that ?

Comment: you want to show red onClick without onClickListener?

Comment: post your code which you have written yet

Comment: I want to show the item in red when the list view appear.

Comment: If you are able to validate absence within `onClickListener()`, it would be easier to handle following behaviours within there.